# What non-grindable items does battfield 1 revolution edition have?

Tags: origin, battlefield-1

I've already got the expansion packs of battlefield 1 in my library from giveaways, but I don't have the base game. My question is which one should I buy, the standard edition or the revolution edition? I already have the four They Shall Not Pass, In the Name of the Tsar, Turning Tides, and Apocalypse expasnion packs. Is there anything else that the revolution edition offers and can not be had by just grinding and playing the game?